# octave plot over image: image disappears when scrolling or zooming (gnuplot)

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I can successfully  plot over an image but then as soon as I scroll or zoom, the image disappears (the plot stays displayed).

I have tried plotting images by using the exact code [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Plotting-on-top-of-Images.html). I Also tried using by using imread/imshow,or imagesc instead of imshow, the behavior remains the same (image disapearing).

Not sure whether this is related or not but when using imread I get the following warning  "|warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel"

I am using octave 3.8.2 and gnuplot (5.0 patchlevel 1) on os X 10.11.1

Any suggestion on how to keep image displayed while scrolling or zooming?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be happenning on my setup (Octave 3.8.1), the plot remains solid throughout scrolling and clicking, can you provide some more information about the problem?

Comment: I have edited my question to add more info. What more infos more specifically would you like?